# Relative inclusion of $L^p$ spaces and norm inequalities.

Tags: integration, lp-spaces

Now, how can one go to prove that, when $1\leq p<q<\infty$, the inclusion $\cal{L}^q\subset\cal{L}^q$ holds for the corresponding spaces? We need to assume that the underlying measure (assumed to be the same for both) is finite, right?

A proof that mentions also the way to prove that for the norms, $\|f\|_p\leq\|f\|_q$ for every $f$ in the particular case when $\mu(X)=1$ would be doubly appreciated. Thanks!

[**Reference**: Cohn, *Measure Theory* ($2^{nd}$ ed.), Exercise 3.3.(9)]

Comment: Yes, if $\mu(E)<\infty$ the inclusion holds

Comment: Hölder's inequality.

Comment: Or just think about what happens on the set where $|f|\ge 1.$

Comment: It is not true that $||f||_p<||f||_q$ for every $f$. Take $f=1$, a constant function on space $E$ such that $\mu(E)=1$, for example.

Comment: I meant less or equal than. Would it work then?  (original message edited). Thank you.  Can you provide a step by step proof?  I was messing around trying to guess where exactly to invoke Hölder's...

Comment: Unfortunately, the new statement is still not true. Consider a constant function on a space $E$ of measure less than 1.

Comment: You're right. I modified the question accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: @zhw Your answer esentially contains the seed for user BigbearZzzz 's precise and gentle argument below. Thanks to all of you.

Comment: @MSC I'm glad I could help. By the way, it is desirable that if you are satisfied with an answer to any of you question, you should mark it as "answered" so that it doesn't remain in the unanswered quo.

Answer (score 2):

I will provide one possible way of dealing with this problem. Let $X$ be a space with $\mu (X)<\infty$, and $p,q\in\Bbb R$ satisfying $1\le p\le q< \infty$. Let $f\in \mathcal L^q(X)$, then
$$\begin{align}
\int_X |f|^p d\mu &= \int_{|f|\le 1} |f|^p d\mu + \int_{|f|>1} |f|^p d\mu \\
&\le \int_{|f|\le 1} 1\  d\mu + \int_{|f|>1} |f|^q d\mu \\
&\le \int_{X} 1\  d\mu + \int_{X} |f|^q d\mu \\
\end{align}$$
Which implies that

> $$||f||_p^p\le \mu(X)+||f||_q^q.$$

Since $||f||_q$ is finite, then so is $||f||_p$. Therefore we have $f\in \mathcal L^p(X)$ for any $f\in \mathcal L^q(X)$, which implies that 
$$
\mathcal L^q(X) \subset \mathcal L^p(X)
$$ 
for $p\le q$, $\mu(X)<\infty$.

Now, what went wrong if $\mu(X)=\infty$? It is not hard to see that the yellowish inequality still holds but it no longer implies that $||f||_p$ is finite. This can be realized on $X=\Bbb R$ and a function $f$ of the form $f=\frac1{|1+x|^r}$ for some suitably chosen $r$.